# PHP If else statement with multiple values

Tags: php

How could i write if else statement in PHP (I'm using Yii2). My problem is I have got a bunch of id. It's Something like this (56,57,58,...88),(101,102,...109) and also (201,202,...209). So in PHP how can i deal with this kind of statement? I want to make statement something like this.

```
if (56,57,58,...88){
echo "test1";
} elseif (101,102,...109){
    echo "test2";
} elseif (201,202,...209){
    echo "test3";
}
```

so is this possible to make it in if else statement or i have to choose another way to deal with these ids?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*This question is not about Yii2 but just about PHP, so I suggested an edit to your question.*

What you want to do is compare the values by the minimum and maximum values of your range. Assuming the value you are comparing is in `$value`:

```
if ($value >= 56 && $value <= 88){
    echo "test1";
} elseif ($value >= 101 && $value <= 109){
    echo "test2";
} elseif ($value >= 201 && $value <= 209){
    echo "test3";
}
```

---

**A little extra info not relevant to this exact question, but just in case:**

If your values are not in a nice range like this, but a bit scattered, e.g. `(1, 3, 7, 8, 12)` and `(5, 11, 44, 45)`, you could either use the [`switch` statement](http://php.net/manual/de/control-structures.switch.php) like this:

```
switch($value) {
    case 1:
    case 3:
    case 7:
    case 8:
    case 12:
        echo "test1";
        break;
    case 5:
    case 11:
    case 44:
    case 45:
        echo "test2";
        break;
}
```

...or `in_array` like this:

```
if (in_array($value, [1, 3, 7, 8, 12])){
    echo "test1";
} elseif (in_array($value, [5, 11, 44, 45])){
    echo "test2";
}
```